# Is i-connectedness really all that new of a concept?

Tags: general-topology

Definition. A subset of a topological space is said to be i-connected if, and only if, it is connected and its interior is non-empty and connected.

The standard example of a connected set that is not i-connected is the union of two tangential disks.

The above is taken from a recent article that I encountered while browsing the web, namely, the following:

“Some properties of i-connected sets” (by Jadwiga Knop, Magorzata Wróbel, en Annales Academiae Paedagogicae Cracoviensis Folia 45 Studia Mathematica VI).

The article presents this material with the air of introducing it for the first time into the literature, but I find it hard to believe that a topic that seems to so naturally suggest itself for exploration would have been overlooked for so long. However, my search of the web finds no other reference to the concept. So my question is: Is i-connectedness really such a new concept as it seems to be?

One complication in searching the web is that fact that the “i” prefix is strongly associated with certain commercial products.